# PHP cURL: Script seems to not continue after successful curl

Tags: php, curl

I have a reasonably simple PHP that runs several curls based on PHP POST values from a form. Once it mangles the POST'd variables as I need it to, it runs 4 curl_init/curl_exec/curl_close in series.

It runs the first 2 curls fine, and prints my output/debug as required. It reaches a third curl, which seems to execute and POST perfectly fine, but doesn't seem to do anything after that. I have basic error capturing (parse JSON response for array/value, if array, echo error, else echo no error).

When **no error** is encountered with the problem curl, it **seems to not continue**. However, if there is an error, it continues. Note I am not explicitly telling the code to continue, it's just a very basic "if else" in PHP. This is for debug, and when I find out why it's misbehaving, die will be used to exit. **I do not tell it to break or die**.

This third, "blocking" curl is the same endpoint as the previous two and returns the same valid JSON as the first two curl calls. I want to know why the script seems to stop when no error is encountered. Is it not continuing due to an open connection? I tried adding "connection close" headers to the problem curl but no difference, as well as a timeout via CURLOPTS.

Below is the code structure used for each cURL.

```php
$curl = curl_init();

echo "<p>Opening curl for <theApplication></p>";

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => '<theEndpoint>',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 1,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'<validJSON>',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$data = json_decode($response);
$results = $data->result[0];
$maintenanceid = $results->ids[0];

$errors = $data->error->data;
   
if ($errors) {
  echo "<p><font color='red'>Error: ".$errors."</font></p>";
} else {
  echo "<p><font color='green'>No errors!</font></p>";
};

curl_close($curl);

echo "<p>Finished the curl! Why aren't you printing me!</p>";
```

Comment: The code in your question doesn't seem to represent the description above. That aside, are you saying that you don't see the _"Finished"_ message after you see _"No errors!"_? Have you made sure you can [see any and all error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/283366)? Have you checked the page source (right click in your browser and select _"View Page Source"_) to make sure it's not just some garbled HTML hiding your message?

Comment: Then you've probably got an unseen error due to the response not being what you expect. In particular, if the response is not JSON or does not contain a `result` property then your code will fail before it reaches the `if`

Comment: In fact I won't even see the "No errors" being echoed. I will only see an echo from that if statement when it's true.

`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Setting the above prints errors about undefined property $data, which doesn't make a lot of sense to me as $data is populated by the json_decode($response).

Based on your feedback I've gone and echoed $response and $data for the problem curl. $response is correctly populated however echo $data; returns `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Comment: Use `var_dump($data)` or `print_r($data)` for displaying objects

Comment: I am an idiot, I just realised I was needlessly putting result into a variable then parsing it for an array again afterwards. After reworking the code to `$maintenanceid = $data->result->maintenanceids[0];` the script continues.

I should have paid more attention to the warning/fatal error. Thankyou for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: There's a reason they're _fatal_ 